# php symfony 4 FosUserBundle cannot login with firewall pattern ^/login & undefined variable _SESSION

Tags: php, symfony

in my Symfony 4 project I am using default FOSUSerBundle configuration which looks llike this:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/login   #problem here   
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            success_handler: fos_authentication_handler
            failure_handler: fos_authentication_handler

        logout: true
        anonymous: true
```

So when I use `pattern: ^/` it works fine, but when I do it like this: `pattern: ^/login` it prevents me from logging in saying that `variable _SESSION is undefined`.  In my controller I am using the following code which works fine when firewall pattern is '^/':

```
$this->get("session")->save();
```

I dont want it to block the base route of my site ('mysite.com/') and I want to implement custom logic there. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: FOSUserBundle is not compatible with SF4/5 therefore it is usage with this SF versions is not recommended. You can use the MakerBundle and create users/registration forms and continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

issue solved

finally I undertand that firewall pattern means pattern which covers all routing naming for the entire site. If it starts with '^/login', all other routes starting not with login wont be covered by firewall and thus error appears. Moreover, I got my index path under restricted access in security.yml so it threw the following error.